# Create a new List immutably and in the functional style

Tags: scala

How to create an immutable List in the functional style from a Seq[String]?

```
def createNewList(old:Seq[String]):Seq[Catalogue] = {

   // for each s in old I want to create a new Catalogue(s)
   // and append it on a new List and then return the List
   // How to do in the functional style?

}

case class Catalogue(name:String) {
  ... do something here with name to create new Cataloge
}
```

thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
val result = old.map(Catalogue(_)) //the result is a Seq[Catalogue]
```